# How to update previous gridview row onrowdatabound

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to update Cell 4 of previous row in order to add a button click event if sVal contains "Field Name" of the current row.

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string sVal = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;
        if (sVal.Contains("Field Name"))
        {
            // update cell[4] of previous row with button click event

            e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
            e.Row.Cells[2].Font.Bold = true;

            e.Row.Cells[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
            e.Row.Cells[3].Font.Bold = true;

            e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
            e.Row.Cells[4].Font.Bold = true;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make class
then this class call at update panel in Auto update panel timer 5 Second..
it is good way...

```
    string sVal = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;
    if (sVal.Contains("Field Name"))
    {
        // update cell[4] of previous row with button click event

        e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
        e.Row.Cells[2].Font.Bold = true;

        e.Row.Cells[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
        e.Row.Cells[3].Font.Bold = true;

        e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
        e.Row.Cells[4].Font.Bold = true;

    }
}
```

Comment: GridView here is dynamically created.